# Formula to calculate first visible row after filtering Sheets vs. Excel

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

After filtering some rows I'm trying to get the first visible value in a given column. 
The following formula works in Excel, but is not for google sheets.
Please see the image for Sheets results.
Formula works on range A2:A4.

I changed the *logical test of the if statement* in the formula, to be as the expected result of the formula (at least the way I understand it) as follows

logical test portion:

```
    SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A4)-ROW(A2),0))
```

expected evaluation of logical test:
        {0,1,2}

Original:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A2:A4,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2,ROW(A2:A4)-ROW(A2),0)),ROW(A2:A4)-ROW(A2)+1))))
```

After Parsing:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A2:A4,MIN(IF({0;1;2},ROW(A2:A4)-ROW(A2)+1))))
```

the 2nd formula works perfectly. as seen in image #3.

Makes sense that the problem is here,  as **Subtotal** is the only formula ignoring hidden rows.

this logical test returns 3 values array {0,1,2}. Each value is the number of *visible* rows in 3 ranges A2:A2,A2:A3,A2:A4 respectively, calculated with the offset function.

Please note image #3, shows I first accidentally parsed the logical test array to {0,1,1} rather than {0,1,2}. It does not really make a change as:

```
    if(1) = if(2) = true
```

What is the difference between Excel and Sheets? or better ask. why it does not work with Sheets?

[image: Google Sheets 3 screen shoots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a helper column with row indexes:

```
A    
1
2
3
```

and use this column in a formula:

`=SUBTOTAL(105,A:A)`

code `105` will find the minimum by column and skip hidden values.